# How to resize a pinned window with just the keyboard?

Tags: visual-studio

I'd like to be able to resize pinnned windows using just the keyboard, for example in the following picture I'd like make the solution Explorer a bit wider.  Is there a way to do this using just the keyboard?

[image]

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdndevs/2009/07/07/tip-resizing-tool-windows-with-the-keyboard-in-visual-studio/  But it is docked, so no.

Comment: @HansPassant yes, I've seen a number of variations of that tip, which I actually use for main windows from time to time already.  I'm picking there's no inbuilt visual studio way of doing it, but I'm picking it can be done with some auto hotkey ninja magic.   Not that I've found anything specifically, but I might have a crack at it if nothing comes from this question.